# Quarkus Lambda with Flyway

Tags: lambda, quarkus, flyway

I'm building a Quarkus Lambda project that uses Flyway to create the database tables. It works great.

However, I don't want to invoke the Flyway migration check script every time the function is called. Obviously, it doesn't make sense in a Lambda function and will just waste resources.

Should I just add a Flyway maven plugin in the project and trigger the schema migration manually? Or is there a more elegant way around?